# Have R script automatically create and update leaflet map/Rpubs or shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-markdown, knitr

I'm tracking birds with satellite telemetry units, and I'm visualizing/sharing the data using a leaflet map and RPubs. I download the telemetry data 1-2 times per week, run the code below to create a leaflet map, then press the 'publish' button and go through the steps to publish the map on RPubs. I'd like to do this automatically in the code, so when I add new data every week and re-run the code it updates the same RPubs page every time, adding new locations to the map. Here's my current setup (and the RPubs link here: http://rpubs.com/jmwiniarski/trackingmap).

```
# Load the libraries ------------------------------------------------------

library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(lubridate)
library(here)
library(sp)

here::here()

# code for source R script to create lines in leaflet:

makeLines <-
  function(dataframeIn, colorMatch) {
    # Unique IDs:
    birdIDs <- unique(dataframeIn$TagID)
    # List of data frames, one per ID:
    tracksList <- vector('list', length = length(birdIDs))
    for (i in 1:length(tracksList)) {
      tracksList[[i]] <- dataframeIn %>%
        filter(TagID == birdIDs[i])
    }
    # List of lines objects (one list item per tagId):
    birdLines <- vector('list', length = length(birdIDs))
    for (i in 1:length(tracksList)) {
      coordMat <- tracksList[[i]] %>%
        select(Longitude, Latitude) %>%
        as.matrix
      birdLines[[i]] <- Lines(Line(coordMat),
                              ID = tracksList[[i]] %>%
                                select(TagID) %>%
                                unique)
    }
    # Combine lines list to spatial lines data frame:
    SpatialLinesDataFrame(
      SpatialLines(birdLines),
      data = dataframeIn %>%
        select(TagID) %>%
        distinct,
      match.ID = FALSE
    )
  }
source('makeLines.R') # create lines connecting sequential GPS fixes

# Read in the data --------------------------------------------------------

# Read each .csv file with tracking data
locs <- structure(list(TagID = c("019", "019", "024", "024", "024", "024", 
"025", "025", "025", "025", "025", "025", "025", "026", "026", 
"026", "026", "026", "028", "028"), Date = structure(c(17704, 
17706, 17706, 17708, 17710, 17714, 17559, 17579, 17587, 17599, 
17609, 17615, 17627, 17559, 17571, 17573, 17575, 17593, 17698, 
17716), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(64768, 64768, 64768, 
64768, 64768, 64768, 80303, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 
64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 64896, 81009, 61184, 61184), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), Latitude = c(56.90802, 56.9080429, 
40.7270012, 40.7275391, 40.7255173, 40.7277451, 27.748, 27.7417603, 
27.7414532, 27.7413254, 27.7408905, 27.7412987, 27.7706108, 27.6432247, 
27.6447868, 27.6444798, 27.6433029, 27.644, 50.3811455, 50.3812485
), Longitude = c(-117.5436935, -117.5441055, -112.0785522, -112.0789871, 
-112.0792694, -112.0784225, -97.125, -97.130661, -97.1301727, 
-97.1277695, -97.126564, -97.1327133, -97.1152496, -97.803688, 
-97.8031998, -97.8071671, -97.8036575, -97.805, -104.5258102, 
-104.5260696), Fix = c("3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "A2", 
"2D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "2D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "3D", "A3", 
"3D", "3D"), Sequence = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 15L, 
20L, 25L, 27L, 32L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 5L, 9L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .Names = c("TagID", 
"Date", "Time", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Fix", "Sequence"))

# Map in leaflet by individual ----------------------------------------------------------
TagIDs <- unique(locs$TagID)

# Set colors for birds:
colorPalette <- colorFactor(palette = rainbow(length(TagIDs)), # could also try primary.colors
                            domain = locs$TagID)

# Plot everything (points and tracks) in a leaflet map
map <- leaflet(locs) %>%
  addProviderTiles(
    "CartoDB.Positron", 
    group = "CartoDB") %>%
  addProviderTiles(
    "Esri.WorldImagery", 
    group = "Satellite") %>%
  addProviderTiles(
    "Stamen.Terrain", 
    group = "Terrain") %>%
  addPolylines(
    data = makeLines(locs), 
    weight = 3,
    opacity = 0.4,
    color = ~ colorPalette(TagID)) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    ~Longitude, 
    ~Latitude, 
    weight = 1, 
    color = 'black',
    fillColor = ~ colorPalette(TagID),
    radius = 5, 
    fillOpacity = 0.8,
    popup=paste(
      '<b style="color:#0000FF">', "TagID:", locs$TagID, '</b>', '<br>',
      "<b>", "Lat:", "</b>", locs$Latitude, "<br>",
      "<b>", "Long:", "</b>", locs$Longitude, "<br>",
      "<b>", "Date:", "</b>", locs$Date, "<br>",
      "<b>", "Time (GMT):", "</b>", locs$Time, "<br>",
      "<b>", "Fix type:", "</b>", locs$Fix, "<br>",
      "<b>", "Fix #:", "</b>", locs$Sequence)) %>%
  addLayersControl(
    position = 'bottomleft',
    baseGroups = c("CartoDB", "Satellite", "Terrain"), 
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
  addLegend(position = 'bottomleft',
            pal = colorPalette,
            values = ~TagID,
            labels = ~TagID,
            title = "TagID")
map
```

Is it possible to use 'rpubsUpload' function in the code to automatically create/update the leaflet map and rpubs website instead of pressing the publish button every time? If so, this would need to be an .Rmd file, correct? Or best done with a shiny app?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but one way to addressing this is to wrap your leaflet into a Shiny App that queries a table in a cloud SQL database. Then you can append new rows to the SQL database and every time the app boots up, it pulls new data from the database.

Comment: @RichPauloo any alternatives would be helpful. Do you know of any resources to do this that I can take a look at?